# Proxy issue with Fabric Beta Publisher and Jenkins in android app

Tags: android, jenkins, build, fabric-beta

I use Fabric Beta Publisher plugin for Jenkins to upload my release in Fabric. I have configure the proxy into Jenkins with plugins -> advanced. Also I have configure the proxys params into my VM. I have a timeout issue . 
Any REX for using Fabric with proxy for build a Android application.

Comment: After a long searching, I discover that Fabric Beta Publisher accept only a proxy transparent without login/pw ... To add the proxy params hostname and port , we must add this params as JAVA options in the console Jenkkins like this  :  System.setProperty("https.proxyHost","proxy hostname")
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort","port Number")